Need help to disconnect outlets from light switches
Several outlets in my home are controlled by light switches which are located in the same room and a few feet away from their corresponding outlet. Each outlet has two plugs, both of them switched (so not a "half hot" scenario). All light switches are of dimmable kind. I do not need this setup anymore, as my rooms have all recessed lights, controlled by those dimmable switches, so I wont be connecting light fixtures to those switched outlets. I would like to use the outlets for other purposes, e.g. computers, printers, etc. Your help are all much appreciated.
Room 1

Room 2


the wires in the pictures are not correctly connected to the plugs... the wire end should have a hook shape

wires look alright to me.  how would you even get a hook behind that brass retainer?

@jsotola Those are what is typically called screw to clamp. You can do a traditional hook between the screw and the clamp. Or you can do the much easier straight wire under the clamp and then you can actually do two wires on each screw - top and bottom of the clamp. Much easier to do (no bending the wire, no risk of looping the wrong direction) and faster. The $0.77 receptacles don't have them, but the $2.61 "Commercial grade" ones have them. Well worth the extra cost - especially since they are better built in other ways that matter for durability/long-term safety.

@jsotola Clamp type are also the preferred type in commercial applications where stranded wire is often used.

When you added the recessed lights did you attach the feed? At a receptacle or the switch? Also note he words "permenantly installed" in NEC 404.14(F) https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/4/equipment-for-general-use#404.14_(F)

We need to see what the wiring looks like at the switch(es).

It isn't clear from your description; are the dimmable switches controlling the can lights by another wire?  Or they controlled by separate switches?
If the former, just disconnect the currently switch-controlled hot wire to the outlets, and connect directly to a hot in the switch box.
If it's the latter, just remove the switch and wire directly to an appropriate hot.

The pictures show the "typical" two cables to each receptacle situation. With unswitched receptacles that means:

One cable hot/neutral from panel (or previous receptacle or other device in the circuit)
One cable hot/neutral going to the next receptacle or other device in the circuit

However, if you only have one duplex receptacle on each switch plus the existing switched lights then you likely have:

One cable switched hot/neutral from switch
One cable switched hot/neutral going to the ceiling lights

In other words, when the ceiling lights were wired up, instead of separating the receptacles from the switches (which is what should have been done and which you are trying to don now) and running a new cable from the switch to the ceiling lights, the ceiling lights were daisy-chained off of the receptacles. Which works but results in switched, and now dimmed, receptacles. Switching receptacles is OK. Dimming receptacles is almost always not OK.
Pictures of the switch wiring and/or the ceiling light wiring will be needed to figure out if this is what is happening. But if each switch box has just two cables and has two white wires connected together and two black wires going to the switch then that's what is going on: switch -> receptacle -> light. And if that's the case then any solution will require new cables.
If the switches and receptacles are on the same wall and in the same stud bay then it should be easy enough to:

Disconnect the black/white cable that connects switch and receptacle

Fish through a black/white/red cable and connect:

White to white in switch box
Black to black plus a black pigtail to switch in switch box
Red to switch in switch box
White to receptacle in receptacle box
Black to receptacle in receptacle box
Remove the other black wire (switched hot to light) from receptacle and connect it to red in receptacle box



